# Dúvidas em relação a 'param' do applet e um archive que aponta para um jar

Tags: java, jar, applet

Eu não consigo entender o que é esse param nessa applet, alguém me explica? E por que a applet tem aquele archive que aponta para um jar? Por que param?

```
<applet code="TesteApplet.class" archive="agora.jar" width=160 height=120>
    <param name="campo" value="senha">
    <param name="formulario" value="formulario">
</applet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo `archive` é um opcional que descreve um ou mais arquivos que contêm classes e outros recursos que serão "pré-carregados".

---

Já os parâmetros especificam os valores que o `applet` precisa para a inicialização e para a sua correta exibição no aplicativo. O arquivo HTML lista parâmetros para o applet nas tags .

É passado desta forma:

```
<param name=[nome] value=[valor]>
```

onde `[nome]` indica o nome do parâmetro, tal como é esperado pela `applet`, e `[valor]` representa a informação a ser passada.

Pra recuperar o valor de um parâmetro, você tem que chamar o método `getParameter()`, passando o valor de `name` como do parâmetro.

**Referências:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/using_tags.html#applet

http://www.dm.ufscar.br/profs/waldeck/curso/java/part33.html

Answer (score 0):

As propriedades param podem ser recuperadas no código do Applet, da seguinte maneira:

```
 String paramCampo = getParameter("campo");
```

Usando o seu código HTML de exemplo, o valor da variável `paramCampo` nesse caso seria "senha".

Quanto ao atributo `archive` da tag applet, ela aponta para o programa Java que foi encapsulado no container `.Jar` quer contém o applet.

Comment: Por que eu preciso apontar para um jar? Esse jar é a minha applet?